# How to access Query parameters in FieldResolver

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Using `type-graphql` I am trying to build an entry-point that returns me a List entity with its meta info like name, description, etc. and also a computed field `content`, that supposed to contain entities added to the list. The entry-point must have `pageNumber` property that should be taken into account when returning the content.

**How can I pass this property from the List entity resolver down to the `content` field resolver?** 
There is @Info decorator that seems to have this information but it does not look like it is supposed to be used for this purpose.

```ts
@Resolver(() => List)
export class MyListResolver {

    @Query(() => List, { nullable: true })
    async list(
        @Arg('id') id: number,
        @Arg('pageNumber', { nullable: true }) pageNumber: number,
    ): Promise<List | null> {

        // Returns list's info
        return await List.findOne(id) || null;
    }

    @FieldResolver(() => [ListEntity])
    async content(@Root() list: List): Promise<ListEntity[]> {

        // How do I access `pageNumber` here so I could return only the requested page of content?

        return listsContentLoader.load(list.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: How list and content are related??? I don't understand why you want to achieve this. Can you make an example or add more information. Thanks!

Comment: content resolves a ListEntity array on the List object. I think it's straight forward, but he asks how he can access to @Arg from root, in his fieldresolver. I have same issue. I can get args in parent query, but they are undefined in FieldResolver. I think it may be a bug.

Comment: I think that's not possible. Cf this issue comment: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/708#issuecomment-698211870